# godep: exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH?

Tags: go, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run `make run`. But getting this. I do not know to how to set this.

Comment: you should set the path to golang bin

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the path variable to where your go package is installed. Typically on ubuntu is installed on the `/bin` folder. So in your case you have to set it to:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Check the documentation here: https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Comment: They can't even get the package installed due to `go` not being found.  Makes sure you also add the bin directory of your go install to the path as well.